# Add polygons with boost::polygon does not compile?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-polygon

May be this is a stupid question and only a simple issue, but I fail compiling a relative simple code. What I try to do is to add/concatenate two polygons using boost::polygon (some pseudocode showing the relevant parts):

```
#include <boost/polygon/polygon.hpp>

boost::polygon::polygon_with_holes_data<int>     baseData; // base data to work with
boost::polygon::polygon_with_holes_data<int>     opData;   // operational data to be applied to base 

fill both baseData and opData via set() and set_holes() here...

boost::polygon::polygon_set_data<int> result=baseData + opData;
```

The last line is where I stumble upon: the compiler says the operator "+" is not known for polygon_with_holes_data:

```
error C2678: binary '+' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'boost::polygon::polygon_with_holes_data<T>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

When I use polygon_data instead of polygon_with_holes_data the same error appears. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Why did you tag this as "C"?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt sorry, done accidentally!

Comment: Try calling `append()` instead. If the operator wasn't defined, it's not defined.

Comment: @jwdonahue the + operator does not perform an append-operation, it is intended to concatenate the polygons on geometry level. There also exists a - operator which is intended to cut one polygon out of the other, so it is completely different what has to be done here. According to the boost-description there should be such operators defined and to be used for that

Comment: Is there a Concatenate function?  Your compiler says there's no plus operator.  Perhaps there's a separate header file that declares that operator?  It's possible there's no `T operator+(T, T)`, but a there might be `T::operator+(T)`, in which case you want `result +=  baseData + opData`.   I tried looking up the members for that class and didn't find any.  I've got a slow and unreliable internet here, so you might have better luck at it than I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only operators I see mentioned in the documentation are on [polygon sets](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/polygon/doc/gtl_polygon_set_concept.htm)

Also, note:

> Operators are declared inside the namespace `boost::polygon::operators`.

So, making sure to actually use them:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/44ebe391cd963381)**

```
#include <boost/polygon/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/polygon/polygon_set_data.hpp>
#include <boost/polygon/polygon_with_holes_data.hpp>

namespace bp = boost::polygon;
using poly = bp::polygon_with_holes_data<int>;
using pset = bp::polygon_set_data<int>;

int main() {
    poly baseData; // base data to work with
    poly opData;   // operational data to be applied to base

    // fill both baseData and opData via set() and set_holes() here...

    using namespace bp::operators;
    pset x = baseData + opData;
}
```